# Display picture in Excel from OneDrive file path

Tags: microsoft-excel, images, onedrive

I have an excel file stored on `OneDrive` and some pictures stored in sub folder on the same drive.

Pictures are uploaded through `PowerApp`.

In my excel file I can only see file path, not actual picture, is there any way to display pictures by file path?

Path is not full (start from the dot) and looks like this: `.\Excel_File_Name_images\3800285862364dbc8790f90884cde108.jpg`

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319334/show-image-from-folder-based-on-cell-value-in-ms-excel